# Make Laptop Cam and Mic available in VM

Tags: virtualbox, audio, webcam, microphone, virt-manager

I want to make the integrated web camera and the audio/microphone available in a windows VM.

Which devices do you need add to the VM via virt-manager?

**PCI**

```
===> lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

**USB**

```
===> lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 5986:0268 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1199:a001 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 17ef:100f Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:6047 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Background**

I need to use a commercial video conferencing system which does not support linux.

Using virt-manager is only my current strategy. If there are easier ways (maybe virtualbox), this is a valid answer, too.

Comment: Have you tried VirtualBox?

Comment: @BigChris not yet. I am happy with virt-manager since some years ... But if this fails, I will give VirtualBox a try.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Player free version worked for me. 
I was able to set up VM's that even included Mac OS and facetime with it successfully.

VMWare player also allowed mapping of drives as well. I agree with above and not use virtualbox, it didn't provide any drivers nor ability to load external hardware.

Comment: I guess virt-manager would work too. But I have no clue which pci or usb devices I need to pass through. That's why I asked this question on superuser.